# Compartir la carpeta public/storage entre dos subdominios

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Tengo un problema al mostrar las imágenes de la carpeta storage con otro proyecto.

Contexto: Tengo una aplicación laravel de punto de venta donde se registran productos (con la imagen).
Por otro lado, tengo una aplicación tipo tienda en lineal igual creada con laravel y en la tienda en lineal muestro los productos creados en mi punto de venta.

El problema está en que las imágenes se encuentran dentro de mi punto de venta y no puedo mostrarlas en la tienda en lineal.

Ya intenté con `storage:link`

```php
public_path('imagenes') => storage_path('/var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/httpdocs/public/storage/app/public')
```

También con:

```sh
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/httpdocs/public/storage/app/public /var/www/tiendaEnLinea/public/storage
```

pero no me funcionan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar un nuevo driver (carpeta) en las configuraciones de Laravel y ponerle un nombre para que se pueda acceder a esta desde la clase Storage, la carpeta debe tener permisos de escritura. El archivo donde se hace se llama Filesystem.php, para mas informacion puedes revisar la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem): Tambien te recomiendo usar un s3 para ambos casos o cualquier otra opcion de disco duro en la nube, asi es mas facil linkearlos a tu proyecto.

Comment: ¿No es posible crear un enlace simbólico a la carpeta donde se encuentran las imágenes?, algo como: public_path('imagenes') => storage_path('/var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/httpdocs/public/storage/app/public')